# Is there an optimal way to split the text into small parts when working with co-reference resolution?

Tags: natural-language-processing

I am working with co-reference resolution in a large text. Is there an optimal way to split the text into small parts? Or the best correct procedure is to use the entire text?

Just for reference, I am using the library [spacy-neuralcoref](https://spacy.io/universe/project/neuralcoref) in Python that is based on [Deep Reinforcement Learning for Mention-Ranking Coreference Models](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D16-1245.pdf) by Kevin Clark and Christopher D. Manning, EMNLP 2016.

Why am I asking about splitting the text?

I am applying coreference to chapters of books (roughly 30 pages of text). All the examples I have seen show situations of coreference applied to small pieces of texts. I applied to a chapter and I found strange results. However, this is not a clear justification for that since the state of art in coreference is about 60%. Am I right?

I didn't check all databases that people use to test coreference but the ones I took a look (like MUC 3 and MUC 4 Data Sets), if I understand well, they were composed by a collection of a small number of paragraphs.

**A test Example**:

> **TST1-MUC3-0001**
>
> GUATEMALA CITY, 4 FEB 90 (ACAN-EFE) -- [TEXT] THE GUATEMALA ARMY
> DENIED TODAY THAT GUERRILLAS ATTACKED THE "SANTO TOMAS" PRESIDENTIAL
> FARM, LOCATED ON THE PACIFIC SIDE, WHERE PRESIDENT CEREZO HAS BEEN
> STAYING SINCE 2 FEBRUARY.
>
> A REPORT PUBLISHED BY THE "CERIGUA" NEWS AGENCY -- MOUTHPIECE OF
> THE GUATEMALAN NATIONAL REVOLUTIONARY UNITY (URNG) -- WHOSE MAIN
> OFFICES ARE IN MEXICO, SAYS THAT A GUERRILLA COLUMN ATTACKED THE FARM
> 2 DAYS AGO.
>
> HOWEVER, ARMED FORCES SPOKESMAN COLONEL LUIS ARTURO ISAACS SAID
> THAT THE ATTACK, WHICH RESULTED IN THE DEATH OF A CIVILIAN WHO WAS
> PASSING BY AT THE TIME OF THE SKIRMISH, WAS NOT AGAINST THE FARM, AND
> THAT PRESIDENT CEREZO IS SAFE AND SOUND.
>
> HE ADDED THAT ON 3 FEBRUARY PRESIDENT CEREZO MET WITH THE
> DIPLOMATIC CORPS ACCREDITED IN GUATEMALA.
>
> THE GOVERNMENT ALSO ISSUED A COMMUNIQUE DESCRIBING THE REBEL REPORT
> AS "FALSE AND INCORRECT," AND STRESSING THAT THE PRESIDENT WAS NEVER
> IN DANGER.
>
> COL ISAACS SAID THAT THE GUERRILLAS ATTACKED THE "LA EMINENCIA"
> FARM LOCATED NEAR THE "SANTO TOMAS" FARM, WHERE THEY BURNED THE
> FACILITIES AND STOLE FOOD.
>
> A MILITARY PATROL CLASHED WITH A REBEL COLUMN AND INFLICTED THREE
> CASUALTIES, WHICH WERE TAKEN AWAY BY THE GUERRILLAS WHO FLED TO THE
> MOUNTAINS, ISAACS NOTED.
>
> HE ALSO REPORTED THAT GUERRILLAS KILLED A PEASANT IN THE CITY OF
> FLORES, IN THE NORTHERN EL PETEN DEPARTMENT, AND BURNED A TANK TRUCK.

Comment: I am applying coreference to chapters of books (roughtly 30 pages of text). All the examples I have seem show situations of coreference applied to small pieces of texts. I applied to a chapter and I found strange results. However, this is not a clear justification for that since the state of art in coreference is about 60%. Am I right? You are saying that the best approach is to input the entire chapter?

Comment: I didn't check all databases but the ones I took a look (like MUC 3 and MUC 4 Data Sets), if I understand well, they were composed by a collection of a small number of paragraphs.